# video element sends multiple network requests

Tags: html, http, html5-video, http-caching

I have a video element with a mp4 source

`<video src="https://dh2jw0564x0cd.cloudfront.net/projects/6a30cb01-4414-4c50-ac7e-c2d9ac30358d/assets/videos/1646314487232_Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4" controls preload="auto"></video>`

looking at the network tab I see inconsistent behavior

1. sometime I dont see the request for the video at all
2. when I press play I see a new request with 206 response (range)
3. sometimes the content length of the first request is the size of the whole video, but I do see following requests (with 206 responses) even though the whole video was already downloaded (wtf)
4. pause and play creates more http requests for the video

I tried to find info online but if someone can shed some light on this it will be very helpful...

All an all it seems very inconsistent and I'm trying to find out if data is being downloaded again even though it is already downloaded...

[network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba4Ee.png)

Comment: Different browsers implement video requesting and rendering differently and even a single browser may change the approach over time. Browsers sometimes  make multiple request and then cancel one, for example cancel a request for the full mp4 when it determines range requests are supported. Additionally, videos may be served from cache. It might be worth choosing a specific video and browser and share the network and timings tabs form the inspector to focus the question.