# Rails video_tag issuing extra GET request resulting in ActionController::RoutingError No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a page that shows user-uploaded videos and pictures. The path for this page is `/users/:id/` and the pictures/videos are located in `/public/media/users/[userName]/`

user_controller:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    posts = @author.posts

    @pictures = posts.select(&:picture?)
    @videos = posts.select(&:video?)
  end
```

views/user/show.html.erb:

```
<% @pictures.each do |picture| %>
    <%= image_tag("/" + picture.path) %>
<% end %>

<% @videos.each do |video| %>
    <%= video_tag("/" + video.path) %>
<% end %>
```

The page loads all of the pictures/videos correctly. For example, one of the generated video tags looks like `<video src="/media/users/user1/example.mp4"></video>` which is perfect.

However, after loading the page Rails seems to issue an extra GET request for each of the videos.

```
Completed 200 OK in 126ms (Views: 13.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms | Allocations: 21392)


Started GET "/users//media/users/user1/vids/example.mp4" for ::1 at 2022-08-13 10:21:25 -0400
Started GET "/users//media/users/user1/vids/example2.mp4" for ::1 at 2022-08-13 10:21:25 -0400
Started GET "/users//media/users/user1/vids/example3.mp4" for ::1 at 2022-08-13 10:21:25 -0400
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/media/users/user1/vids/example.mp4"):

  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/media/users/user1/vids/example2.mp4"):

  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/media/users/user1/vids/example3.mp4"):
```

Some observations:

- This is only occurring for videos, no extra requests are generated for pictures
- Rails seems to be prepending the controller name to the start of these paths

Why are these requests being issued?

Comment: What happens if you remove the slash from the route?

Comment: Is it maybe trying to get thumbnails/posters? https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/video_tag

Comment: @Chiperific Without the slash in the route it complains that the file can't be found in the asset pipeline. I also tried passing an argument for the screenshot/posted but it had no effect

Answer (score 0):

First, I have no idea why the requests are happening twice, I suspect Rails is either trying to speed up page loads by delaying loading the actual videos until after the page has rendered or it is making the second request to try and get a `:poster` value from the video object (see docs for [`video_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/video_tag))

But, I think this is probably intended behavior and the problem isn't that the 2nd GET request is happening, the problem is that the 2nd GET request has a bad URL.

I think I have an idea why the 2nd call's URL is bad.

My thought is that Rails doesn't have all the `[userName]` folders added to the asset pipeline.

Hence why you need to have the '/' before the picture and video path.

But, because the folders aren't in the pipeline, they are being resolved by just appending the generated video route to the current route, hence why you are seeing two backslashes together in the 2nd GET calls.

**IF** these folders are dynamically created, adding them to the asset pipeline without restarting the app is beyond me, but probably possible with some meta Rails programming.

If these folders are static, or the app can be restarted after a new folder is created, you can make sure they get added to the [asset pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

First, see if these folders *are* in the asset pipeline:

> You can view the search path by inspecting [Rails.application.config.assets.paths](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-assets-paths) in the Rails console.

If they aren't in there, it might be because you've put them in `/public` but haven't enabled public assets:

> In previous versions of Rails, all assets were located in subdirectories of public such as images, javascripts and stylesheets. With the asset pipeline, the preferred location for these assets is now the app/assets directory. Files in this directory are served by the Sprockets middleware.
>
> Assets can still be placed in the `public` hierarchy. Any assets under `public` will be served as static files by the application or web server when `config.public_file_server.enabled` is set to true. You should use `app/assets` for files that must undergo some pre-processing before they are served.

```rb
# application.rb

module YourAppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.public_file_server.enabled = true
    ...  
  end
end
```

**or this behavior can be customized per environment:**

```rb
# production.rb, development.rb, or test.rb

Rails.application.configure do
  ...
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  ...
end
```

If this still doesn't fix it, you might have to manually add `public/media/users/*` to the pipeline [like this](https://learn.co/lessons/images-and-the-asset-pipeline).

Comment: "Rails is either trying to speed up page loads... or it is making the second request to try and get a :poster value..."

I think I've ruled both of these possibilities out. I replaced the <%= video_tag... %> with a basic html <video> tag and set autoplay set to true. No change in behavior but I assume that html video tags don't have posters/screenshots and I can also see that the videos start playing before the second round of GET requests starts.

I also tried both adding public assets and disabling the asset pipeline entirely, with no effect.

Comment: So you were able to confirm that all the videos, and the custom user folders, are available to the asset pipeline?

Comment: Maybe it's not Rails doing the request at all, but the browser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72085188/video-element-sends-multiple-network-requests